# Interagir com array multidimensional - PHP

Tags: php

Gostaria de saber como fazer uma interação com o array multidimensional sem usar o foreach.

```
$arr1 = array('id' => 1, 'nome' => 'Joao');
$arr2 = array('id' => 2, 'nome' => 'Maria');

$arrTotal = array($arr1, $arr2);
```

Quero pegar só os campos *id*. Então quero uma resultado da seguinte forma: `[1, 2]`.

Valeu.

Comment: E porque não `array($arr1['id'], $arr2['id']);` ?

Comment: Você quer somar os `id` de todos os arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você estiver utilizando PHP 5.5 ou superior, poderá tirar proveito da função [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php).

```
$result = array_column($total_array, 'id');
```

E simples assim terá o resultado esperado.

Para versões anteriores ao 5.5, você pode criar a função array_column você mesmo

```
if(!function_exists("array_column")) {
    function array_column($array,$column_name) {
       return array_map(function($element) use ($column_name) {
          return $element[$column_name];
       }, $array);
    }
}
```

Ou então apenas utilizar o [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

```
$result = array_map(function($item) {
   return $item['id']; 
}, $arrayTotal);
```

Answer (score 2):

Penso que sua questão não expressa realmente o que você está tentando dizer.
Da forma como você descreve, simplesmente faria-se dessa forma:

```
$arr1 = array('id' => 1, 'nome' => 'Joao');
$arr2 = array('id' => 2, 'nome' => 'Maria');

$arrTotal = array($arr1['id'], $arr2['id']);
```

No entanto, talvez `$arr1` e `$arr2` sejam elementos de outro array, tal como isso:

```
$map = array(
    array('id' => 1, 'nome' => 'Joao'),
    array('id' => 2, 'nome' => 'Maria'),
    array('id' => 7, 'nome' => 'Pedro'),
);
```

Com essa estrutura, sua pergunta faz sentido, pois realmente haverá uma iteração. Sem foreach:

```
$map = array(
    array('id' => 1, 'nome' => 'Joao'),
    array('id' => 2, 'nome' => 'Maria'),
    array('id' => 7, 'nome' => 'Pedro'),
);

$result = array_map(function($a) { return $a['id']; }, $map);
```